# How to show a selected item from popup menu button as text?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a popup menu button with a text widget below it. I want the text widget to show what the user has selected from the popup menu button.
[Popup menu button unpressed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PV6Qp.jpg)
[Popup menu button pressed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdE9J.jpg)
*Right now in the `_mlTextWidget()` below I could only figure out how to hardcode a specific choice.*

I am unsure how to connect the selected item with the text widget. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
// A class containing the menu items
class MLConstants {
  static const String FourX = '4x';
  static const String TenX = '10x';
  static const String TwentyFiveX = '25x';
  static const String FourtyX = '40x';
  static const String SixtyThreeX = '63x';

  static const List<String> choices3 = <String>[
    FourX,
    TenX,
    TwentyFiveX,
    FourtyX,
    SixtyThreeX
  ];
}


// Popup menu button
Widget _cameraTogglesRowWidget() {
 return PopupMenuButton<String>(
      icon: const Icon(
        Icons.zoom_in,
        color: Colors.white,
        size: 30,
      ),
      onSelected: choiceAction3,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
        return MLConstants.choices3.map((String choice3) {
          return PopupMenuItem<String>(
            value: choice3,
            child: Text(choice3),
          );
        }).toList();
      },
    );
  }


// What happens when a menu item is pressed
  void choiceAction3(String choice3) {
    if (choice3 == MLConstants.FourX) {
      print('4x');
    } else if (choice3 == MLConstants.TenX) {
      print('10x');
    } else if (choice3 == MLConstants.TwentyFiveX) {
      print('25x');
    } else if (choice3 == MLConstants.FourtyX) {
      print('40x');
    } else if (choice3 == MLConstants.SixtyThreeX) {
      print('63x');
    }
  }


// The text widget showing the selected item
  Widget _mlTextWidget() {
    return Container(
        child: (Text("${MLConstants.FourX}",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 13,
              color: Colors.white,
            ))));
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place it in state in `onSelected` and use it in your `Text`. Like so:

```
  String selectedChoice3;

  void choiceAction3(String choice3) {
    setState(() {
      selectedChoice3 = choice3;
    });
    if (choice3 == MLConstants.FourX) {
      print('4x');
    } else if (choice3 == MLConstants.TenX) {
      print('10x');
    } else if (choice3 == MLConstants.TwentyFiveX) {
      print('25x');
    } else if (choice3 == MLConstants.FourtyX) {
      print('40x');
    } else if (choice3 == MLConstants.SixtyThreeX) {
      print('63x');
    }
  }


// The text widget showing the selected item
  Widget _mlTextWidget() {
    return Container(
        child: (Text("${selectedChoice3 ?? ''}",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 13,
              color: Colors.white,
            ))));
  }
```

Of course, assuming these are in a `State` class. If not, you can convert your `StatelessWidget` to a `StatefulWidget` automatically in [IntelliJ](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-ide-shortcuts-for-faster-development-2ef45c51085b) or [VSCode](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-visual-studio-code-shortcuts-for-fast-and-efficient-development-7235bc6c3b7d).